# spark-shell - Not able to access java functions in jars

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jar, spark-shell

I have started exploring spark 2 days back. So I am pretty new to it. My use case is around accessing a java function present in an external jar in my scala code which I am writing in spark-shell. But I think I am not loading my jar properly. Here is what I am doing

```
spark-shell --master local[2] --jars pathToJarsWithComma --conf="spark.driver.extraClassPath=pathToJarsWithColon" --conf="spark.executor.extraClassPath=pathToJarsWithColon"
```

This is how I launch my spark-shell with all the required jars being passed. And whenever I am trying to call the java static function like :

```
rdd1.collect.foreach(a=>MyClass.myfuncttion(a))
```

I am getting error as :

```
<console>:26: error: not found: value MyClass
```

I want to know if my understanding is correct. Can we use java functions in spark by loading external jars. If yes, then what I am doing wrong here. Please guide.

Comment: Have you imported it? You need to import class first with `import my.package.MyClass` (`my.package` is of course example).

Comment: Are you sure that the jar you are passing is containing the class you are referring to?

Comment: Yes I have the class present in the jar. I did import the package like : `import my.package._` hoping that all the classes under this package will be loaded. But I am getting the same error as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

We can load java functions in Spark by loading external jars. I am not sure whether you need the confs you added at the end to make this work. For me, I tried out the following to test loading a jar in a spark shell.

```
./bin/spark-shell --master <spark url>  --jars /home/SparkBench/Terasort/target/jars/guava-19.0-rc2.jar
```

After that in the shell, I tried to access a field from a class in the jar.

```
scala> import com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes
import com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes
scala> UnsignedBytes.MAX_POWER_OF_TWO
res0: Byte = -128
```

As you can see, I was able to access fields from the external jar. You can also test out whether you can access the Class by a simple field from it.